# Delete variable number of repeated chars at end of line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

**Edited:** after testing commands from answers below on a new file, it worked. Now I discovered that my data file is **CRLF**.

---

Consider this kind of data file:

```
41;34;41;34;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
2;5;0;24;;5;2;5;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
0;27;;28;-20;28;20;28;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
92;111;32;44;60;119;124;120;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

What is the best way to delete the repeated commas at the end of line?

Observe that the number of repeated `;` **is not constant**.

Replacing two comas `;;` by nothing is not good since: (1) the number at end could be odd; (2) there could be some `;;` in the middle that have to be left there.

**Desired output:**

```
41;34;41;34
2;5;0;24;;5;2;5
0;27;;28;-20;28;20;28
92;111;32;44;60;119;124;120
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use sed:

```
sed 's/;*$//'
```

It removes zero or more `;` characters at the end

Comment: Sorry, but I tried both `sed 's/;*$//g' foo.csv ` and `cat foo.csv | sed 's/;*$//g'` but no success.

Comment: @Gary_W, I suppose that `./x` should be replaced by `./foo.csv`, right? Did not worked also.

Comment: I really don't know why, but after copying the data from the post above and pasting on a new file, the `sed` command worked! But not with my original file.

Comment: `cat ./foo.csv | dos2unix | sed 's/;*$//' | unix2dos | sponge ./foo.csv` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk, the output could be in LF, no problem.

Comment: Now you told me how to proceed, I discovered `sed -i -e 's/\r\+$//' filename` to convert to LF and `sed` now works.

Comment: It sounds like `sed 's/;*\(\r*\)$/\1/'` is what you really should be using so you don't change your line endings just to remove the trailing semicolons.

Comment: @EdMorton, what is the meaning of `\1`?

Comment: It's a backreference to reproduce whatever the `\(...\)` capture group found. Try `echo 'm4k7t3' | sed 's/\(.\)\(...\)\(.*\)/<\1><\2><\3>/'`

Answer (score 2):

`sed` is the right tool but also with `awk`

```
$ awk '{gsub(/;+$/,"")}1' file
```